# Compiling WordNet 3.0 on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, wordnet

I'm trying to get WordNet to work on my Notebook but it fails in the make step of the process as follows:

```
WaldundWiesenComputer:WordNet-3.0 Gnaddel$ make
make  all-recursive
Making all in doc
Making all in html
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in man
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in pdf
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in ps
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in dict
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in include
Making all in tk
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in lib
Making all in wnres
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in src
if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -I.. -I../include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/local/include -I.. -I../include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/local/include    -g -O2 -MT wishwn-stubs.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/wishwn-stubs.Tpo" -c -o wishwn-stubs.o `test -f 'stubs.c' || echo './'`stubs.c; \
    then mv -f ".deps/wishwn-stubs.Tpo" ".deps/wishwn-stubs.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/wishwn-stubs.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_findvalidsearches’:
stubs.c:43: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c:55: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_bit’:
stubs.c:72: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c:78: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_search’:
stubs.c:92: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c:105: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_glosses’:
stubs.c:117: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_fileinfo’:
stubs.c:132: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_byteoffset’:
stubs.c:147: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_senseflag’:
stubs.c:162: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_contextualhelp’:
stubs.c:178: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c:183: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_reopendb’:
stubs.c:193: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
stubs.c: In function ‘wn_abortsearch’:
stubs.c:207: error: ‘Tcl_Interp’ has no member named ‘result’
make[2]: *** [wishwn-stubs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Both XCode and the command line toolset are installed in their current versions.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you installed Tcl/Tk?

Comment: The problem is that the newest version of Tcl has dropped Tcl_Interp, and the WordNet guys dont seem to be on the ball here.. I have tried to find a solution for this. Check out this bug report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=902561

Comment: I've "solved" my problem by not compiling it myself but using prebuilt packages. There are Ubuntu packages (named "wordnet") and packages in the macports packages for OSX (named "wn").

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem on Ubuntu. It got resolved machine when I uninstalled the latest version of Tcl (i was trying it with Tcl 8.6 first). And installed an older version of Tcl 8.4. With older version Wordnet installed flawlessly